# Query from another database in wordpress at the same server

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

How can i query posts from another database in wordpress engine. For example now i have wordpress installed, but i can`t integrate old site database.
Old site was not in wordpress, but i think it is not a problem, because there is no problems for me to change structure of old db in phpmyadmin.
I think that the best method in this situation - query from another database with custom query on a custom wordpress page template. 
Any ideas ?
Please advice me methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem on MySQL to do cross database queries.

```
SELECT * FROM [database_name].[table_name];
```

Comment: Thank yo very much for answer. But with same query there is no linking, or when user clicks to a post link there is no loading of post.

Comment: @Ronin this is quote a vague comment... What do you mean?

Comment: @janw - I want to say that with similar mysql query which say jordeu i can query only titles of posts. For example when i click to this titles there is no post content loading.